# Write a PL/SQL program using an implicit cursor that displays the whole table OILPRICE on the screen with a third column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**Table Data:**

```
01-FEB-21   2.25
02-FEB-21   2.36
03-FEB-21   2.47
04-FEB-21   2.51
05-FEB-21   2.4
```

**Question**

Write a PL/SQL program using an implicit cursor that displays the whole table OILPRICE on the screen with a third column (Change; it does not exist in the table) in the following format:

```
Date= 01-FEB-21 Price= 2.25 Change= 0
Date= 02-FEB-21 Price= 2.36 Change= + 
Etc.
```

**Now here is the explanation of how to compute the Change value.**

- If the Price in the current row is larger by more than 0.1 than the value in the PREVIOUS row, print a + as the value of Change.
- If the Price in the current row is smaller by more than 0.1 than the value in the PREVIOUS row, print a - (minus sign) as the value of Change.
- If the absolute value of the difference between the price in the current row and in the previous row is less than 0.1 then the value of Change should be 0.
- In the first row the value of Change should be 0.

**Cursor I made**

```
begin
        for implicit_cursor in
             (select * from oilprice)
        loop
            dbms_output.put_line(
            'Date= ' || implicit_cursor.dateline 
            || '  ' || 'Price= '|| implicit_cursor.price
        );
       end loop;
end;
```

You can add the third column in the above code or you can make your own.

Thank you!!!

Comment: at a minimum, you need to have an ORDER BY clause to order by date, no?

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test order by datum;

DATUM           PRICE
---------- ----------
01.02.2021       2,25
02.02.2021       2,36
03.02.2021       2,47
04.02.2021       2,51
05.02.2021        2,4
```

PL/SQL anonymous block which does what you wanted. How? It uses the `lag` analytic function to fetch previous row's `price` and compares it to current row's value in order to *calculate* the `change` value.

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in
  3      (select datum,
  4              price,
  5              lag(price) over (order by datum) previous_price,
  6              --
  7              case when price - lag(price) over (order by datum) > 0.1 then '+'
  8                   when price - lag(price) over (order by datum) < 0.1 then '-'
  9                   else '0'
 10              end as change
 11       from test
 12       order by datum
 13      )
 14    loop
 15      dbms_output.put_line
 16      ('Date = '     || to_char(cur_r.datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||
 17       '  Price = '  || to_char(cur_r.price, 'fm999G990D00') ||
 18       '  Change = ' || cur_r.change
 19      );
 20    end loop;
 21  end;
 22  /
Date = 01.02.2021  Price = 2,25  Change = 0
Date = 02.02.2021  Price = 2,36  Change = +
Date = 03.02.2021  Price = 2,47  Change = +
Date = 04.02.2021  Price = 2,51  Change = -
Date = 05.02.2021  Price = 2,40  Change = -

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```